# How to minify HTML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, minify

Is there some tool (or Rails itself) that can minify HTML (like what [Jammit](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/) does for CSS and JS files) ?

Secondarily, what is the best practice here, and is it even worth minifying the html? 
(this is for a site that will be served to mobile phones, so keeping weight down is important)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enabling compression at HTTP level will serve you much more than minifying HTML, however [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net) is good to apply transformations to HTML, including removing extraneous spaces , comments, etc...

Comment: Agree, if you have gzip, HTML minification will almost have no impact in your transfer size, unless you have a LOT of HTML comments. If it's for the spaces, gzip does a pretty good job.

Comment: Google Page Speed recommends that you minify your HTML, in addition to using gzip compression. How can you minify the HTML with Rails?

Answer (score 13):

Well, you can remove most white space by using the HAML gem and the following lines in your `config/application.rb` file:

```
Haml.init_rails(binding)
Haml::Template.options[:format] = :html5
Haml::Template.options[:ugly] = true
```

More information:
http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#ugly-option

Comment: Good option if you have haml in your rails application

Comment: Can you use this if you are using ERB in your app. Like, only use this feature of HAML?

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://prettydiff.com/?m=minify&html to minify your HTML.

Minifying HTML is extremely complicated and easily misunderstood.  True minification involves removing comments and all unnecessary white space from the syntax, which would include an white space in your content, so be sure you are using a tool that knows what it is doing.