# Rails 3.1: Minify HTML?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, minify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to minify HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768362/how-to-minify-html)

As far as I know, Rails 3.1 will automatically minify the JavaScript and CSS. Is it possible to minify the HTML as well?

Such an option must be optional of course, since you can make whitespaces meaningful using `white-space: pre`, but in most cases, they are just useless to the client.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768362/how-to-minify-html

Comment: but makes it harder to work with the code later.